# NODE JS: grouping data from join table

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have two tables that I join using PostgreSQL for my quiz app. After retrieving the join table, the data does not look like what I expected.
Is there any way I can group the data with JavaScript function?

Here is my table:

```
  CREATE TABLE questions (
    q_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question text
  )

  CREATE TABLE choices (
    c_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    choice text,
    question_id BIGINT REFERENCES test1 (q_id)
  )
```

my code to retrieve the data from join table:

```
  const getQuestionAndChoices = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const getAllData = await pool.query(
          'select * from questions join choices on questions.q_id = answer.question_id')

      return res.status(200).json(getAllData.rows)
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json(error.message)
    }
  }
```

the result:

```
[
    {
        "q_id": "1",
        "question": "question 1",
        "c_id": "1",
        "choice": "choice_1",
        "question_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "1",
        "question": "question 1",
        "c_id": "2",
        "choice": "choice_2",
        "question_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "2",
        "question": "question 2",
        "c_id": "3",
        "choice": "choice_1",
        "question_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "2",
        "question": "question 2",
        "c_id": "4",
        "choice": "choice_2",
        "question_id": "2"
    }
]
```

what I expected:

```
[
    {
        "q_id": "1",
        "question": "question 1",
        "choice": ["choice_1", "choice_2"],
        "question_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "q_id": "2",
        "question": "question 2",
        "choice": ["choice_1", "choice_2"],
        "question_id": "2"
    },
]
```

Comment: What in *answer.question_id* is *answer*? Please include *all* questions and choices with questions.q_id and questions_id equal to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to aggregate `choice` right in the SQL like this:

```js
select q_id, question, question_id, array_agg(choice) as choice
from questions join choices on questions.q_id = choices.question_id
group by q_id, question, question_id
order by q_id, question, question_id
```

(I also replaced `answers` with `choices`)